# Phonegap offline maps with OpenLayers and Open Street Maps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, openlayers, openstreetmap

I've been trying to do some research about how to use OpenLayers + OpenStreetMaps on Phonegap, so I found this: [Navigate through a pre-known map offline using Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296525/navigate-through-a-pre-known-map-offline-using-phonegap?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but I was wondering if someone can provide me a working example on how to use it, a github repo or something like that.

I'm building this app for business listings but in some cases the mobile device won't have internet connection, so what I need is to download the map tiles of an area when wifi is available, or another thing that I'm gonna need is for example trace a route from point A to point B (when I have wifi) and download the map tiles from the rout, in case in the road I don't have internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example at http://geospatialscott.blogspot.com/2012/04/phonegap-leaflet-tilemill-offline.html where someone put together an example of offline maps in a PhoneGap application using Leaflet & TileMill.  There is a linke to GitHub in that page for the demo.  I haven't tried it myself, but looks like it could put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, appreciate it.