# openlayers to native android app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, openlayers

My problem is that i have map which written on openlayers. i will integrate it with jquery mobile or somethings else. 
But i need to do native application so i have to use phonegap. that is my idea. First is it possible ? and if yes where can i start ? 
if no which way i follow ? 
and also do you know sample or example about that ?

Thanks 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

YES. Its possible.

https://github.com/netgis/ol3

[Phonegap offline maps with OpenLayers and Open Street Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840913/phonegap-offline-maps-with-openlayers-and-open-street-maps)

Comment: So i just use phonegap and openlayers. Also i have to add this conversation, openlayers it is dynamiclayer and it will get data from geoserver

Comment: It's not an issue if its offline or from remote server.

Comment: No it is not ofline but for integration it doesnt matter . I think like that i will look and try thanks anyway

Comment: Question was about some links to learn more.. And more over it does not make sense personally to me, to explain here the concepts which is already there in the links.. Sorry, its my personal thought